# Why does Jetty server hang when trying to debug Java Spring project in IDEA 12.1?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, jetty

I use IntelliJ IDEA 12.1, Jetty 9.0 server, Spring, Apache CXF in order to create and debug REST service.
When I try to debug my app, it freezes at this line:
`1512 [Scanner-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@639f9c92: defining beans`

Where should I search for the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: I don't know why, but try pausing and restarting. It's probably not blocked there by the way, that's just the last thing that was logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IntelliJ debug settings you can select whether to suspend All threads or just the one Thread you have the break point on. If you set it to Thread, your app will keep running its other threads.